# Ubuntu not installing on toshiba satellite

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, nvidia, 13.10

I recently bought a Toshiba Satellite s70 and customized it to have nvidia GEFORCE graphics card.  I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my old laptop and created a 13.04 and 13.10 install usbs.  I jump through the hoops to get to the usb boot, and am able to get to the grub menu.  From there, when I try either the "Try Ubuntu Without Installing" or the "Install Ubuntu" option, the screen seems to shut off, and nothing happens.  If I look at the install code thing, it says `quiet splash` and I've tried `nomodeset`but all that does is load a shell.  Basically startx fails, and I just get the I/O stream.  I want to install it side by side windows 8, any solutions?

Comment: Have you dual monitors set up or dual graphics card?